# JOptionPane char input

Tags: java, input, dialog, char

I'm working on a hangman program in Java, and part of my code will be to obtain single letter guesses from the user through the JOptionPane dialog box (this is the input method my professor prefers as opposed to the scanner).

I'm pretty new and have only gotten input from this dialog box as a string then converted the input to an int or double. I've been trying to find a way to get the input as a char but still use the dialog box.

Anyone have a solution or know where I could look to find one?

here's my code so far if you need it for reference.. the last line is where I got stuck

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] words = {
        "javascript", "declaration", "object", "program", "failing"
    };

    Random rnd = new Random();

    String rndWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];

    char[] displayArray = new char[rndWord.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < rndWord.length(); i++) {
        displayArray[i] = '_';
    }

    char[] alphabet = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', +'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', +'x', 'y', 'z'
    };
    String hangman = "Let's Play Hangman!!" + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "\n" + Arrays.toString(displayArray) + "\n" + "       ";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hangman + " " + Arrays.toString(alphabet) + " ");
    String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a letter: ");

}
```

Comment: Why there is `+` in `displayArray[i] += '_';`?

Comment: typo. thanks for catching it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is loop until the user puts in one and only one character. Then, convert the `String` to a `char`.

There is no way to return directly a `char` from `JOptionPane#showInputDialog` ([see Oracle's Website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html))

---

### Solution

```
String guess;
while ((guess=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a letter: ")).length() != 1);
char charGuessed = guess.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I used the following method:

```
 //get letter
public static char guess()
{
    String guessStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("Enter a letter to guess: ");

    // check if have at least one letter
    if (guessStr.length() > 0)
    {

    }
    char guessChar = guessStr.charAt(0);
    return guessChar;
}
```